# How do I clear the previous text field value after submitting the form with out refreshing the entire page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am doing a web application using **javascript** and **html** that has a form containing a text field, button. When I enter a number in that text field and submit by clicking on that button, text areas are generated dynamically. Once my form is submitted some text areas are created but if I am not satisfied with existing text areas then again I enter some value with out refreshing page. But the text field value entered previously prevails showing the new text areas below the existing text areas on the page.

So, how do I **clear the value with out refreshing the page.**

```
<div>
    <html>
     <input type="text" name = "numquest" id ="numquest" value="" size="5" style="" disabled>
     <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="getFields();">
</div>
    </html>
    
    <javascript>
      var num_q=document.getElementById('numquest').value;
     //code for dynamic creation
    </javascript>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. You create a textarea on the fly, and if the button is clicked again, it's wiped out (removed), and a new one comes up?

Comment: How about something like $('#numquest').val('');

Comment: Thank all for your responses. I will try that out.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**try this:**

**Using jQuery:**

You can reset the entire form with:

```
$("#myform")[0].reset();
```

Or just the specific field with:

```
$('#form-id').children('input').val('')
```

**Using JavaScript Without jQuery**

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnsubmit" onclick="submitForm()">

function submitForm() {
   // Get the first form with the name
   // Hopefully there is only one, but there are more, select the correct index
   var frm = document.getElementsByName('contact-form')[0];
   frm.submit(); // Submit
   frm.reset();  // Reset
   return false; // Prevent page refresh
}
```

Comment: The top solution works in my case, but afterwords, a tooltip appears, which says "please fill out this field" for the first field in my form. All fields are required in my form. Any way to prevent that from happening? The page is not refreshing.

Answer (score 28):

You can set the value of the element to blank

```
document.getElementById('elementId').value='';
```

Answer (score 6):

**Assign empty value:**

```
document.getElementById('numquest').value=null;
```

**or, if want to clear all form fields. Just call form reset method as:**

```
document.forms['form_name'].reset()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just do as you get that elements value

```
document.getElementById('numquest').value='';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="user-name" /><br>
<input type=submit value="submit" id="submit" /> <br>
</form>

<script>
$(window).load(function() {
$('form').children('input:not(#submit)').val('')
}

</script>
```

You can use this script where every you want.

Answer (score 1):

**It will clear all the fields.**

```
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach((input) => (input.value = ""));
```

Comment: This will also set all radio/checkbox/button values to blanks, something worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form id="some_form">
<!-- some form elements -->
</form>
```

and jquery

```
$("#some_form").reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's better to use

```
$('#form-id').find('input').val('');
```

instead of

```
$('#form-id').children('input').val('');
```

incase you have checkboxes in your form use this to rest it:

```
$('#form-id').find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` or `.value` is IMHO the best solution because it's useful with Ajax. And `.reset()` only works after page reload and APIs using Ajax never refresh pages unless it's triggered by a different script.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue and I solved by doing this:

```
.done(function() {
                    $(this).find("input").val("");
                    $("#feedback").trigger("reset");
                });
```

I added this code after my script as I used jQuery. Try same)

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#feedback").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "feedback_lib.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: $("#feedback").serialize()
                }).done(function() {
                    $(this).find("input").val("");
                    $("#feedback").trigger("reset");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <form id="feedback" action="" name="feedback" method="post">
        <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" />
        <br />
        <input id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="surname" />
        <br />
        <input id="enquiry" name="enquiry" placeholder="enquiry" />
        <br />
        <input id="organisation" name="organisation" placeholder="organisation" />
        <br />
        <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
        <br />
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="7" cols="40" placeholder="сообщение"></textarea>
        <br />
        <button id="send" name="send">send</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to the `onsubmit` property:

```js
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = e => {
   e.target.submit();
   e.target.reset();
   return false;
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit