# How do i refresh text fields after i click submit button?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

i'm trying to empty my text fields on html after i login. After i log out, the data that i inserted is still there. How do i do that? Here's my html, thankyou for your help.

```
<div class="tabs-striped  tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">
    <div class="tabs">
      <a class="tab-item active" href="#/app/login"><i class="icon ion-unlocked"></i> Login</a>
      <a class="tab-item" href="#/app/signup"> <i class="icon ion-person"></i> Sign Up </a>
    </div>
 </div>

<ion-view view-title="Sign In" class="loginBg" hide-nav-bar="true" >

  <ion-content class="padding">

    <div class="row responsive-sm padding remvoeBP">
        <div class="col">
            <center><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Item Img" width="275" height="90"></center>
            <br>
            <div class="list list-inset">
                <label class="item item-input">
                  <input  type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" ng-model="user.phone" ng-maxlength="13" onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57' required autocomplete="off">
                </label> 

                <label class="item item-input">
                  <input type="password" id="pin" placeholder="PIN" ng-model="user.pin" ng-maxlength="6" onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57' required autocomplete="off">
                </label>
             </div>

            <div class="loginButton">
                <button class="button ion-unlocked button-block button-positive" ng-click="login();" > 
                    Login 
                </button>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: use [autocomplete](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp) attribute.

Comment: @RohitKishore i used that already

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jquery like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form').each(function() { 
this.reset() 
});
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery use this:

You can reset your form with - `$("#myform")[0].reset();`
or

```
$('#form-id').children('input').val('')
```

If you are using JavaScript:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnsubmit" onclick="submitForm()">

function submitForm() {
   // Get the first form with the name
   // Hopefully there is only one, but there are more, select the correct index
   var frm = document.getElementsByName('contact-form')[0];
   frm.submit(); // Submit
   frm.reset();  // Reset
   return false; // Prevent page refresh
}
```

Hope it helped.

Possible duplicate of :[How do i clear the previous text field value after submitting the form with out refreshing the entire page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416803/how-do-i-clear-the-previous-text-field-value-after-submitting-the-form-with-out)