# How does one automatically delete the contents of an html text field after passing the text to a php script?

Tags: html, text, reset, enter

I'm working on a program that identifies the customer of an order based on the contents of an order via a bar code scanner. I'm nearly there, but I'm trying to tighten it up to be more physically efficient. As of now, it requires the text field contents to be manually deleted or else the bar code scanner will append the next value on to the previously scanned code. How do I get the text field to reset while still being able to successfully pass off the previous bar-code to my php script.

I've tried a few JavaScript functions that auto cleared the text field, but for some reason these prevented the bar codes from being passed to the php script. I suspect the problem is somewhere in this section of code.

```html
<form name="basket-form" action="phpFiles/search.php" target="resultsFrame" method="post">
    <p>Scan items here:</p>      
    <input id="textInput" type="text" name="item" onfocus="this.value=''"/>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>
    <input type="submit" name="clear" value="Clear"/>
    <p></p>
</form>
```

I would like my program to behave as such:

1. Scan a bar code.
2. Its value is passed off to my php script.
3. This bar code is deleted from the text field.
4. Cursor stays in the text field so that next item can be scanned immediately.

Steps two and three seem to be mutually exclusive and, as a result, my main problem.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416803/how-do-i-clear-the-previous-text-field-value-after-submitting-the-form-with-out) question may have what you need:

1. Give the form tag an ID of `form`.
2. Add `onclick="submitForm()"` to the search button.
3. Add this JS code:

```
function submitForm() {
   var form = document.getElementByID('search'); // Get form object
   form.submit(); // Submit
   form.reset();  // Reset
   return false; // Prevent page refresh
}
```