# Clearing the text of an input tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, knockout.js

I am currently having trouble clearing the text inside of an `input type="text"` tag in my application. I have been able to clear the inputs of all fields by setting the necessary `observable (knockout.js)` to the default value, but with this input I can not find a way to do so.

The input tag I need to clear in the `.cshtml` file:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search for Users…" id="users" class="form-control" data-bind="autoComplete: Users, value: SelectedFilteredUser, optionsText: 'DisplayName', optionsValue: 'Value',autoCompleteOptions: {autoFocus: false}" />
```

I have tried my usual `knockout.js` approach of setting the observable's value to a default value:

`self.SelectedFilteredUser(null);` and `self.SelectedFilteredUser("");`

NOTE: `self.SelectedFilteredUser(null);` does set the value inside of the `input` to null as seen when I click it's associated add button I created, but the text is still inside the `input` tag. This is what I have used to clear my other inputs but it has not worked here surprisingly.

After looking over numerous StackOverflow posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416803/how-do-i-clear-the-previous-text-field-value-after-submitting-the-form-with-out) one, I have tried other solutions such as,

With jQuery: `$('#users').val('');` and normal JavaScript access to the element:  `document.getElementById('users').value='';`

These both have no effect at all.

If anyone has any idea how I can clear this `input type="text"` tag in my `.cshtml` file, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: `document.getElementById('users').value('');` <-- value is not a method

Comment: @epascarello My bad, I realized my error. Trying it with the proper syntax of `document.getElementById('users').value='';` produces the same result. Updated my question with the proper code.

Comment: see if you have other elements with same ID "users" in your case, also just do a console.log($('#users').val()); to see what value it is holding if any

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I have done this after the `document.getElementById('users').value='';` is executed, in the console it is printing an empty line. So the value is correctly changed, but the text still resides in the input text box.